# Why doesn't this bor and bnot expression give the expected result in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, binary-operators

why doesn't this bor bnot give the expected result in powershell?

To find the last address in an ipv6 subnet one needs to do a "binary or" and a "binary not" operation.

The article I'm reading (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660429/Subnetting-with-IPv6-Part-1-2) describes it like this:

```
(2001:db8:1234::) | ~(ffff:ffff:ffff::) = 2001:db8:1234:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
```

Where | is a "binary or" and
~ is a "binary not"

---

In powershell however, I try it like:

```
$mask = 0xffffffff
$someOctet = 0x0000
"{0:x4}" -f ($someOctet -bor -bnot ($mask) )
```

and I get 0000 instead of ffff

Why is this?

Comment: Why are you expecting `ffff`? `-bnot 0xffffffff` is `0`, why would `0x0000 -bor 0` should be not `0`? BTW `ffff:ffff:ffff::` is the short form of `ffff:ffff:ffff:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000`.

Comment: Because of the tutorial...maybe it's a bad tutorial.

Comment: I'm trying to do an octet at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial is doing a `-not` of the entire subnet mask, so `ff00` inverts to `00ff` and similar for longer Fs and 0s; you aren't doing that, so you don't get the same results.

The fully expanded calculation that you show is doing this:

```
1. (2001:0db8:1234:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000) | ~(ffff:ffff:ffff:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000) 

2. (2001:0db8:1234:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000) |  (0000:0000:0000:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff) 

3. = 2001:db8:1234:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
```

Note how in step 1. to step 2, the `not` is inverting the pattern of Fs and 0s, switching the subnet mask around, and switching it around between the *bit* where the prefix ends and the *bit* where the host part begins.

Then step 3 `or` takes only the set bits from the left to keep those numbers the same (neither zero'd nor ffff'd), and *all* the set bits from the right (to ffff those, maxing them to the max IP address within that prefix).

In other words, it makes no sense to do this "an octet at a time". This is a whole IP address (or whole prefix) + whole subnet mask operation.

Where the tutorial says:

> & (AND), | (OR), ~ (NOT or bit INVERTER): We will use these three bitwise operators in our calculations. I think everybody is familiar -at least from university digital logic courses- and knows how they operate. I will not explain the details here again. You can search for 'bitwise operators' for further information.

If you aren't very familiar with what they do, it would be worth studying that more, before trying to apply them to IP subnetting. Because you are basically asking why `0 or (not 1)` is `0` and the answer is because that's how Boolean logic "or" and "not" work.

---

Edit for your comment

`[math]::pow(2,128)` is a lot bigger than `[decimal]::maxvalue`, so I don't think Decimal will do.

I don't know what a recommended way to do it is, but I imagine if you really wanted to do it all within PowerShell with `-not` you'd have to process it with  `[bigint]` (e.g. `[bigint]::Parse('20010db8123400000000000000000000', 'hex')`).

But more likely, you'd do something more long-winded like:

```
# parse the address and mask into IP address objects
# which saves you having to expand the short version to 
$ip = [ipaddress]::Parse('fe80::1')
$mask = [ipaddress]::Parse('ffff::')


# Convert them into byte arrays, then convert those into BitArrays
$ipBits = [System.Collections.BitArray]::new($ip.GetAddressBytes())
$maskBits = [System.Collections.BitArray]::new($mask.GetAddressBytes())


# ip OR (NOT mask) calculation using BitArray's own methods
$result = $ipBits.Or($maskBits.Not())


# long-winded way to get the resulting BitArray back to an IP
# via a byte array

$byteTemp = [byte[]]::new(16)
$result.CopyTo($byteTemp, 0)
$maxIP = [ipaddress]::new($byteTemp)

$maxIP.IPAddressToString

# fe80:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
```

Comment: So if there's 128-bits in an ipv6 address...you'd have to store both  that and the subnet mask, in PowerShell as a `[decimal]` since the `[decimal]` datatype is 128-bits...that's a big variable!  If store the address like this: `[decimal]$ipv6addr=0x20010db812340` do I end up with all zeros after that to the right?  Because if I type `[decimal]$ipv6addr=0x20010db8123400000000000000000000` all I do is get yelled at by `pwsh` with a  ParentContainsErrorRecordException

Comment: I've edited my answer to reply, because there's more to say than I can put in a comment. (Now I see why you were trying to do it an octet at a time? haha).

Comment: heheh...wait, and why was that?  Why was I trying to do it one octet at a time?  I mean I learned about bitwise operators at school...I used bit flags just the other day in Powershell to display a COM dialog box with my choice of OK / OK and Cancel, and No Icon / Alert Icon / Stop Icon / Info Icon but that's not quite the same thing as this...I'm certain there weren't as many bits; I believe there were only 32.

Comment: I was assuming you split it up because you can't fit an IPv6 address or mask in an `[int]` (which is `[System.int32]`), which I wasn't thinking about at all until you mentioned it. (IPv4 fits in unsigned `[uint32]`, but there's nothing like that big enough for IPv6)

Comment: Note that finding the max ip address in an ipv6 subnet is directly dependent on how many `f's` (15's) you give to line 4 in your example above.

Comment: $ip = [ipaddress]::Parse('2001:0db8:1234::')

# Finding the max ip address is directly dependent on how many f's you give (the mask):
#
#  Like if your prefix is '2001:0db8:1234::'
#  Then your mask should be 'ffff:ffff:ffff::' 
#
$mask = [ipaddress]::Parse('ffff:ffff:ffff:f::')

Comment: The mask needs as many bits set as the length of the prefix in bits. In IPv4 that can mean the mask is `ff.ff.ff.00`  for a /24 or it can be `ff.ff.80.00` for a /23, or other digits, it's not always `f`. I haven't worked out how this plays out in IPv6, it might be arranged so that they always end on neat boundaries, or it might be not all `f`s all the time.